# Displaying timecode using NSTimer and NSDateFormatter

Tags: iphone, xcode, nstimer, nsdateformatter

I am very close to completing my first iphone app and it has been a joy.  I am trying to add running timecode using the current time via an NSTimer displaying the current time (NSDate) on a UILabel.  NSDate is working fine for me, showing hour, minute, second, milliseconds.  But instead of milliseconds, I need to show 24 frames per second.

The problem is that I need the frames per second to be synced 100% with the hour, minute and second, so I can't add the frames in a separate timer.  I tried that and had it working but the frame timer was not running in sync with the date timer.

Can anyone help me out with this?  Is there a way to customize NSDateFormatter so that I can have a date timer formatted with 24 frames per second?  Right now I'm limited to formatting just hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds.

Here's the code I'm using right now

```
-(void)runTimer {
 // This starts the timer which fires the displayCount method every 0.01 seconds
 runTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: .01
            target: self
             selector: @selector(displayCount)
             userInfo: nil
              repeats: YES];
}

//This formats the timer using the current date and sets text on UILabels
- (void)displayCount; {

 NSDateFormatter *formatter =
 [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];

 // This will produce a time that looks like "12:15:07:75" using 4 separate labels
 // I could also have this on just one label but for now they are separated

 // This sets the Hour Label and formats it in hours
 [formatter setDateFormat:@"HH"];
 [timecodeHourLabel setText:[formatter stringFromDate:date]];

 // This sets the Minute Label and formats it in minutes
 [formatter setDateFormat:@"mm"];
 [timecodeMinuteLabel setText:[formatter stringFromDate:date]];

 // This sets the Second Label and formats it in seconds
 [formatter setDateFormat:@"ss"];
 [timecodeSecondLabel setText:[formatter stringFromDate:date]];

 //This sets the Frame Label and formats it in milliseconds
 //I need this to be 24 frames per second
 [formatter setDateFormat:@"SS"];
 [timecodeFrameLabel setText:[formatter stringFromDate:date]];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you extract the milliseconds from your `NSDate` - this is in seconds, so the fraction will give you milliseconds.

Then just use a plain format string to append the value using `NSString` method `stringWithFormat`:.

Comment: After some playing around, I'm still not sure how to implement this.  I have been able to successfully do what you suggested, but it seems I'm missing a whole chunk of math that actually does the 24 frames per second conversion.  Instead of showing 100 milliseconds per second, I need to show the numbers run through 0-23 every second and I need it to be in perfect sync with the NSTimer so that it actually completes and restarts when each second is over.

Answer (score 1):

Lots-a-overhead with NSFormatter + NSDate. Plus it seems to me that NSDate doesn't provide a "simple" microtime situation for simple stuff.

Mogga provided a nice pointer, here's a C / Objective-C variant:

```
- (NSString *) formatTimeStamp:(float)seconds {
    int sec = floor(fmodf(seconds, 60.0f));
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d.%02d.%03d",
                        (int)floor(seconds/60/60),          // hours
                        (int)floor(seconds/60),             // minutes
                        (int)sec,                           // seconds
                        (int)floor((seconds - sec) * 1000)  // milliseconds
             ];
}

// NOTE: %02d is C style formatting where:
// % - the usual suspect
// 02 - target length (pad single digits for padding)
// d - the usual suspect
```

See [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390706/how-can-i-pad-an-integer-on-the-left-with-zeros) for more info on this formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Processing/Java equivalent that's fairly straightforward to repurpose.

```
String timecodeString(int fps) {
  float ms = millis();
  return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d+%02d", floor(ms/1000/60/60),    // H
                                              floor(ms/1000/60),       // M
                                              floor(ms/1000%60),       // S
                                              floor(ms/1000*fps%fps)); // F
}
```