# How can I pad an integer on the left with zeros?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have the following variable:

```
NSNumber *consumption = [dict objectForKey:@"con"];
```

Which returns 42.  How can I pad this number to 10 digits on the left, leading with zeros.  The output should look as,

> 0000000042

or if it were 420,

> 0000000420

Comment: possible duplicate of [Zero-pad digits in string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324358/zero-pad-digits-in-string)

Comment: @Deepak -- that's php -- not quite the same.

Comment: oops. I linked to the wrong question but you will do what you do in `C` as seen in the answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Format string integer with leading zeros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985170/format-string-integer-with-leading-zeros) and [How to pad the integer with the preceeding 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563825/how-to-pad-the-integer-withe-preceeding-0) and [How to get 1 digit integer into a 2  digits number in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253666/)

Answer (score 100, accepted):

```
NSString *paddedStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%010d", 42];
```

EDIT: It's C style formatting. %nd means the width is at least n. So if the integer is 2 digit long, then you will have length 3 string (when %3d is used). By default the left empty spaces are filled by space. %0nd (0 between % and n) means 0 is used for padding instead of space. Here `n` is the total length. If the integer is less than `n` digits then left padding is used.

Comment: If I were only padding 3 characters would it just be %03d in the format?

Comment: Please check the edit. Also you can experiment yourself with various lengths and numbers.

Answer (score 17):

The `Objective-C` way,

```
NSNumberFormatter * numberFormatter = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[numberFormatter setPaddingPosition:NSNumberFormatterPadBeforePrefix];
[numberFormatter setPaddingCharacter:@"0"];
[numberFormatter setMinimumIntegerDigits:10];

NSNumber * number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:42];

NSString * theString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:number];

NSLog(@"%@", theString);
```

The `C` way is faster though.

Comment: @George I don't know about cleaner. `NSNumberFormatter` is certainly more verbose, but I'd argue it's clearer as far as showing intent. (Granted in this case the sprintf format is not exactly rocket science anyways.)

Comment: I have never cared whether NSNumberFormatter can do this. Always used C style (may be because I have come from C background). +1 though for the Obj-C style.

Comment: @George cleaner surely but this one's clearer as Daniel has said. But for such trivial use case, the `C` way is the way to go.

Answer (score 8):

You can't in the `NSNumber` itself. If you're creating a string from the number or using `NSLog()`, simply use the appropriate format, e.g.

```
NSLog(@"%010d", [consumption intValue]);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do pretty much any number formatting you would ever want with [NSNumberFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html). In this case I think you would want to use the [setFormatWidth:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNumberFormatter/setFormatWidth%3a) and [setPaddingCharacter:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNumberFormatter/setPaddingCharacter%3a) functions.

Answer (score 1):

with variable **`num_digits`**

```
NSString* format =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%%0%zdzd", num_digits];
NSString *theString = [NSString stringWithFormat:format, 42];
```

Answer (score 0):

**E.g. Fill the rest with zeros, 5 digits:**

```
NSInteger someValue = 10;
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%05ld", someValue];
```

Equivalent of `.02f` for float number when you need only 2 digits after the dot.

So there you have 0 = fill with zeros, 5 = the number of digits and type.

Answer (score 0):

## **Solution for Swift 3**

```
let x = 1078.1243
let numFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 1 // for float
numFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 1 // for float
numFormatter.minimumIntegerDigits = 10 // how many digits do want before decimal
numFormatter.paddingPosition = .beforePrefix
numFormatter.paddingCharacter = "0"

let s = numFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(floatLiteral: x))!
```

**OUTPUT**

"0000001078.1"