# NSLog with 2 digits display

Tags: objective-c, nslog

Here I have an

```
int x=3;

NSLog(@"%i", x);
```

How to have it displayed like "01"?
and if x=12 to have it displayed like "12"?
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I pad an integer on the left with zeros?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390706/how-can-i-pad-an-integer-on-the-left-with-zeros)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about `"%02d"` ?

or `"%02i"` ?

(See man printf for formatting information or [cocoadev NSLOG](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSLog))