# number formatter : I need 01 not 1

Tags: iphone, ios, timer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I pad an integer on the left with zeros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390706/how-can-i-pad-an-integer-on-the-left-with-zeros)

In my iPhone app I am calculating time in this manner.

```
int timeTakeInSeconds = (int)(self.timeTaken*[constants timer]);
int timeTakenMins= (int)(timeTakeInSeconds/60);
int timeTakenSecs =(int)(timeTakeInSeconds%60);
NSString *timeText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Time %d:%d",timeTakenMins,timeTakenSecs];
```

By this I am getting second as 1,2,...10, 11..and so on. But I need as 01, 02, 03...10, 11, 12..and so on..How can I do this? Is there any way to do this by number formatter? Please help.

Answer (score 7):

Try using `%d:%02d` instead of just `%d:%d`. This is using the standard C-style printf formatting options. The documentation can be found at [Format Specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265).