# Create a stopwatch with zeros before numbers

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, timer, numbers

I've made a sort of "stopwatch" in my app. Basically, I have an int (let's call it `number`) that increments every 0.1 seconds, and a label (let's call it `label`) that updates when `number` does. `label`'s text is the String form of `number`.

This is working fine, but I'd like to get my label to have the "old-school video game" format, with zeros before the numbers themselves. For example, when `number` is actually 4, I want `label` to say "00004." When `number` is 2,341, I want `label` to say "02341." Etc.

How do I do this? I can take answers in either Swift or Objective-C.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390706/how-can-i-pad-an-integer-on-the-left-with-zeros Does this help?

Comment: String formatting references the IEEE standard.  See here for more details: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html

Comment: See `NSNumberFormatter`.

Comment: @JeremyAnantharaj That worked, thanks. I'll take it as the solution.